# How to work with result of count function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do a query counting how many employees are in each department that have more than 1 employee and with employee numbers 6 or greater, I have:

```
 Select DepartmentName, count(EmployeeNumber) as "Number of Employees"
 From department d, employee e
 Where d.DepartmentName = e.Department and e.EmployeeNumber <=6 
 Group by d.DepartmentName;
```

This fills all requirements except for the part about having more than 1 employee, Is there a way to only execute the rest of the code for results that return 2 or greater from the first line?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `HAVING` clause. Note though that it is applied after the whole thing is counted.

```
Select DepartmentName, count(EmployeeNumber) as "Number of Employees"
From department d, employee e
Where d.DepartmentName = e.Department and e.EmployeeNumber <=6 
Group by d.DepartmentName HAVING count(EmployeeNumber) > 1;
```

Comment: Not sure if this alias would work. I would probably stick with `HAVING COUNT(EmployeeNumber) > 1`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Select DepartmentName, count(EmployeeNumber) as "Number of Employees"
    From department d, employee e
    Where d.DepartmentName = e.Department  
    Group by d.DepartmentName and e.EmployeeNumber <=6
    HAVING count(EmployeeNumber) > 1 ;
```

Comment: This is not what was asked. He is referring to the number of employees, not the employee number. Besides, your way is very inefficient, because `HAVING` is applied after all records are received.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the `and e.EmployeeNumber <=6` bit is probably misplaced.